# How To solve the following error in windows phone 8 application?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, geolocation, location

I'm developing windows phone 8 application.

I need to get user current location Details.

I try with following code taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

C# :

```
 1  private void OneShotLocationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 2   {if ((bool)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] != true)
 3      {
 4               return;
 5       }  
 6       Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
 7       geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
 8       try
 9       {
 10           Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
                maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
               timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
                );

            LatitudeTextBlock.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
            LongitudeTextBlock.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80004004)
            {
                // the application does not have the right capability or the location master switch is off
                StatusTextBlock.Text = "location  is disabled in phone settings.";
            }
            //else
            {
                // something else happened acquring the location
            }
        }
    }
```

I Got error in line number 10.

**The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.**

I 'm new to windows phone application. now only i start the learn basic in WP8 .

Plz tell how to solve this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have used `await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync()` now you can only use await with async methods.

so what you have to do is whenever you used async method just declare the method aysnc

like:`private async void OneShotLocationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

instead of `private void OneShotLocationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Answer (score 2):

Follow the error instruction. Change

```
private void OneShotLocationButton_Click
```

to

```
private async void OneShotLocationButton_Click
```